# CreateUserWithEmailandPassword stops when entering while loop?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I'm trying to build a login system for my app. I am trying to make sure I am logged in before I move onto my next activity but firebase seems to stop trying to log in if I enter a while loop. Like seriously wtf? I am building this in android studio btw.

Here is some code:

```
void handleLogin() {
//Check our form
    if (!validateForm()) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "All Fields Required",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return;
    }
    //Sign in the user
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new     OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>  () {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
 }

/*************************************************
 * ON CREATE - The Activity runs from here!
 *************************************************/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);

   //Checking authState from Firebase
   mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
               isLogged = true;
               System.out.println("Logged in: " + isLogged);
            } else {
               Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
       }
    }
};

//Pop up for when adminID is activated
adminIDField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
adminIDField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            showPopUp();
        else
            System.out.println("Admin ID entered...");
    }
});

// Create Profile Button
createProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
createProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar timeOut = (Calendar)currentTime.clone();
        timeOut.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        emailString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        passwordString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        firstNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        lastNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        apartmentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MENU");

        handleLogin();

        while(!isLogged){ //THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM OCCURS
            System.out.println("Authenticating...");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //handleDataStorage();
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

For some reason when I don't have the while loop in there it logs me in just fine, but when I include the login while loop it stays there forever. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work (maybe the auth listener doesn't fire when the thread is asleep), but why do you need a while loop if  the listener fires only when auth state changes?

Comment: @RohitNavarathna I need it because for some reason (I think it's an asynchronous issue) my app will blow through my functions without waiting for it to actually log into firebase and then mess up a bunch of user creation stuff. So I want to wait until auth state changes (or some given amount of time) and then move onto my next activity.

Comment: Why not just start the new activity in the `(user != null)` condition of the auth state listener?

Comment: @RohitNavarathna ...thank you so much. I have spent so long on this and hadn't thought about as something as simple as this. I'm new here is there a way to give you rep points?

Comment: I guess you could upvote the comment. But I don't see the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a spin loop of `Thread.sleep()` to wait for something to happen is a very bad idea. Android (and most modern environments) implement event driven models that remove the need to do this.

If you look at your code, it boils down to:

```
 doThingA();
 waitForThingA();
 doSomethingThatDependsOnThingA();
```

In a event driven model you would instead write this as:

```
doThingAandThen(doSomethingThatDependsOnThingA);
```

If you look at the code you already have, you can find examples where this pattern is already follow. For example, this code responds to when the authentication state of the user changes:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
           isLogged = true;
           System.out.println("Logged in: " + isLogged);
        } else {
           Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
   }
}
```

You want to handle data storage and transition to a different activity when the user is signed in. By putting that code into this so-called auth state listener, you can accomplish the same without a wait loop:

```
//Checking authState from Firebase
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
           Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
           isLogged = true;
           handleDataStorage();
           //startActivity(intent);
        } else {
           Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
   }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, it was mentioned previously up above in the comments but this is really great explanation of the issue I was having. Thanks!